# Group theory and Schur’s lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a little bit confused by consequence of Schur’s lemma: “irreducible representation of any abelian group must be of dimension one”.
The proof is quite simple but i have some doubts: for exemple if we take G-4 abelian group with his rappresentation over R^2 it’s very clear that reflection matrix commute with all rappresentations of group but it is not one dimensional... why i am in wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this question is likely to be closed because it makes no sense. Schur's lemma is about _representations_ of _abelian_ groups. You are asking about an _element_ of order $2$ that commutes with everything in a nonabablian group. No element is "one dimensional". These things have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: This is not irreducible.

Comment: Just last question... because a group rappresentation be reducible it has got to be  about the same basis vector, right?